# What's the best way to tie a mobile app user to their online profile?

Tags: iphone, android, authentication, mobile, uuid

Let's say I have a killer mobile app named X. I have lots of users and some users want a desktop version of X. How do I associate my mobile users profile with their new website profile? I don't want to have a username/password on the mobile device, because all of my users are on mobile and have a unique mobile device id already.
I was thinking about generating a short UUID in the cloud, send it to the device and when the user signs up for the website they just input their UUID and email.
Is that the best way to do it? Is there a better way?

Comment: If the user has multiple devices, how do you decide which device to associate with their website?  One website per device, even for the same user?

Comment: Good question. I could provide a way to port your profile to another device. I want to know the "best" way to handle mobile and website users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrate with Google's auth.  The phone will pop up and ask you which (of all the Google accounts you associate with your phone) you want to use.  Then you website and/or other apps need to be able to handle Google's sign-in.

Comment: This is the same thing as FB Connect essentially, except there are more FB users than Google Accounts users. This is probably a pretty good solution on Android though.

Comment: While there may be more Facebook users than Google users in general, I'm betting there are more Android users with Google accounts than Android users with Facebook accounts. ;)  (Doesn't the phone force you to setup a Google account during setup?)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like OpenID, where in you have one Id which can be associated to multiple devices as it would be user specific and there will not be any issue as such.

For example, we have something like SO has implemented on it login page.

Comment: @David: That was just an example, but there are other options out there.

Comment: I know there are several ways to do. What is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

By using the user's unique device ID, you potentially limit the user to a single mobile device. (What happens when the user gets a new phone/tablet?) If you are providing a service across multiple platforms, (e.g. mobile, desktop, and web,) I don't think it would be outlandish to require a username and password.

Another option would be to leverage another platform that already does authentication, such as Facebook Connect, or OpenFeint. Of course, it should simply be an option: users shouldn't be required to have such an account to use your service.

Comment: I don't want the user to have to create their account on a mobile device if its not necessary. It makes for a bad UX on mobile. Remember my users start on a mobile device not a website. I like Fb Connect, but I would have to offer an alternative as well like you said.